# Versioning Files - Multiple sites, multiple repositories

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository, git-svn

Right now we are using Subversion as our versioning system but we are open to switching to Git or whatever else to get this to work.

We only know the basic SVN/Git commands so hopefully somebody can explain how to do what we want in a way that would make sense to us.

The image below shows the workflow we would like, and shows it much better then I could explain it.

[image: Versioning Workflow]

My questions are:

Is it possible to do?
Is Subversion capable of doing it? Or do I need to switch to Git (or Git-SVN)?

Just looking for some information to get me pointed in the right direction.

**EDIT:** Will I be able to do this if the second repository (Site #2 - Staging & Production) is on a different remote server than Site #1 (Staging & Production)?

Comment: What is meant by "SVN up"?

Comment: @Randyaa `svn up` is short for `svn update`

Comment: So are you saying you want an SVN repository on each of the staging and production sites? If that's what you mean the GIT or Mercurial seem to lend themselves fairly well to what you're talking about.

Comment: @Randyaa I believe there would have to be a repository for Site #1, and another for Site #2. But Site #2 would have to also update from Site #1. Make sense? :s

Comment: It sounds like you have it all worked out. What is your question?

Comment: @Randyaa I guess... if it's possible to do? Is Subversion capable of doing it? Or do I need to switch to Git (or Git-SVN)? Just some information to get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You can do this with any Version control system. You just need to check code out from one site and into another. A distributed version control system like GIT or MERCURIAL would probably be a bit easier but that's subjective.

Comment: You shouldn't use version control for any of this. You should use a real deploy tool to deploy things to your staging/production environments, and you should use whatever code-reuse mechanisms your language supports to share code between master/client site.

Comment: @meagar Sounds cool, but I have no idea what you're saying. I am coding in PHP, self-taught, nor do I hang out with any other programmers so my terminology is limited.

Comment: @meagar - "You shouldn't use version control for any of this" RLLY?! You (and any developer) **must to use VCS** in any development process. Choosing deploy tools|methods is **next and unrelated** question

Comment: @LazyBadger Thanks, but "duh". I'm not talking about *not* using VCS (and nobody "must" do anything, regardless of how fervently you believe it). I'm suggesting that none of the tasks in question are appropriate for version control - **obviously** he should still be using some form of version control for change management. Choosing deploy tools/methods is not the "next and unrelated" question, that **is his question**. He is moving code between development/staging/production environments.

Comment: @Draven I didn't really use any programming-specific terminology, except maybe "deploy"?. If you want to work on code in a development environment, and then send that code to a staging or production environment, that is usually called 
"deploying". You "deploy to staging" or "deploy to production". Neither Git or SVN are meant to be used for deploying code. They *can* be used in this capacity, but you're better off using a tool which is purpose-built for this. "Code reuse" is pretty self-explanatory. You have two projects which share code. That's code-reuse.

Comment: @meagar I much appreciate you going into further details.I'll have to look up "deploy tools" and how I can use them for my websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do?

Yes

> Is Subversion capable of doing it?

Yes. Six (mandatory) branches in single Repository in easiest case (multirepository setup is also possible, but wil require more tricks with more headache) + rather complex post-commit hook for deploy task

> do I need to switch to Git (or Git-SVN)?

You *can* switch to any pure **DVCS** (without bridge to abandoned SVN), although this is not necessarily: just for *more natural* merges and avoiding "SVN Refactoring Hell". With SVN-background I'll recommend to consider Mercurial, not Git - less cry, less headaches, more real work instead of struggle against difficulties and non-obviousnesses

Comment: Thought of another question... Will I be able to do this if the second repository (Site #2 - Staging & Production) is on a different remote server than Site #1 (Staging & Production)?

Comment: @Draven - "related" repositories for SVN (CVCS in common) is possible (with caution) solution, but it's **Bad Idea (tm)** (use branches in signgle repo). For DVCSes amount and placement of repositories and deploy targets does not matter at all